# sp_BlitzWho while executing gives error message as 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COALESCE'.' in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

To know the spids which are causing slow down/blocking each other; I am trying to use 'sp_BlitzWho' by brilliant Brent Ozar; however on executing on SQL SERVER 2008; am getting message as below.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1643
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COALESCE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1651
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

The First Responder Kit (of which sp_BlitzWho is a part of) [is not supported](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) in such an old version of SQL Server. As from the docs:

> The First Responder Kit runs on:
>
> SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019, 2022 on Windows - fully
> supported.
>
> SQL Server 2008 R2 and earlier - not supported since it's
> out of Microsoft support, but check the Deprecated folder for older
> versions of the scripts which may work, depending on your versions and
> compatibility levels.

Try `sp_WhoIsActive` instead, [it should work](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive) on older versions too:

> sp_WhoIsActive is a comprehensive activity monitoring stored procedure
> that works for all versions of SQL Server from 2005 through 2019 and
> Azure SQL DB.

As an obligatory side note: SQL Server 2008 R2 has been out of support since 2019, so like you've noted, modern tools might not work. Consider upgrading to a supported version instead.

Comment: Database compatability level is 80. It runs for those where database compatibility is above or equal to 100. What can we use for SQL SERVER 2008 database compatibity 80.

Comment: @user206045 You can use [alter database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16) to change the compatibility level, but you really are solving the wrong problem here.

Comment: Hi @user206045,

Actually it is a production db and I can't alter compatability settings as some features of application may stop running. Is there any other alternative.

Comment: @user206045 Yes, there's the other tool I've suggested you to try. You can also change BlitzWho's source and maybe work around the offending statement.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.